# How to eliminate blocking CSS which is fonts?

Tags: javascript, css, html, fonts, pagespeed

I currently am using Google fonts which are included in my `<head>` tag via Rails application.scss like so:

```
`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700');`
```

Google PageSpeed is saying I need to "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" When I move the font CSS to the bottom of the page, whenever the page load the entire page jumps.

How can I make Google fonts non-blocking but not have a page that jumps when it finishes loading?

Comment: That's exactly what blocking means.  If you don't want to render your page until the fonts load, you need a blocking load.

Comment: What you are talking about is `FOIT`.  Here are some articles to help you out.  1. https://css-tricks.com/fout-foit-foft/  2. https://www.lockedowndesign.com/load-google-fonts-asynchronously-for-page-speed/  3. https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-events.html

Comment: @SLaks thanks, I get that but there must be some tricks out there to make the page not jump/jitter etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can read a nice article about this very problem [here](https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/loading-web-fonts-asynchronously/)

The thing is that you won't be able to get rid of that jumping problem (unless the custom font has the exactly same properties as the font being replaced).

> And there you have it. If you load the page for the very first time you will see the fallback font immediately, followed by the web font once it loads. Subsequent visits will load the web fonts from cache and show them immediately. It’s the best of both worlds.

So yeah, long story short, you can either have performance or you can avoid FOUC, but not both.